# Rearranging Logarithm Form to Exponential Form

Tags: c#, logarithm, exponential

I've got a series of logarithms used in a minecraft mod, and I'm designing a program that uses these logarithms to calculate operation time values for the machines within that mod. The problem I'm having is that I have to re-arrange approximately 30 logarithms into their exponential form. (I can do this by hand, but it would be much easier if I could get a program to do it for me)

These logs are of the base 2, and here's an example one:

```
T = 900 - 60 * Log2(Speed + 1)
```

In code this would look like this:

```
T = 900 - 60 * Math.Log((Speed + 1), 2);
```

Of course, this formula can be put straight into C# using Math.Log (As above). However, the rearranged formula looks something like this:

```
2^((-900+T)/-60) - 1 = Speed
```

How would I go about creating a program that can convert between these two forms (Take the input as one of the logarithms, and the programs output would be the exponent form)? There is a Math.Exp method listed in the Math Library on MSDN (C#), however it deals with logarithms of the base e, not base 2.

Note: T means ticks, there are 20 ticks in a second

Note 2: All 30 of the Logarithms use a similar format to the listed one above, the only difference being the first two numbers (eg instead of 900 - 60, it might be 1200 - 60, or 480 - 35 and so on).

Comment: You're looking for `Math.Pow(a,b)`.

Comment: That solves part of the problem, thanks :) But then there's the re-arrangement of the actual logarithm into the other form. On paper, we actually move the equation from one side of the = to the other, so positive values end up being negative, as seen above. Is there any easy way to code for this?

Comment: So you're saying you want us to provide you an expression solver... given some expression, solve form some variable in that expression... that's not a trivial task, and not one for us to just do for you...

Comment: Any advice on where I could look into creating one? I've been told this could be rather difficult. I'm also aware that I can't rephrase the question to ask for specific tools or whatever else because then the question would be marked off topic. So I'm kinda stuck here, I've got a problem, but a rather limited idea on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Speed = Math.Pow( 2, ( T - 900 ) / -60 ) - 1
```

A more general formula for this answer:

```
Speed = Math.Pow( 2, ( T - C1) / -C2) - 1
```

Where C1 and C2 are constants. In the particular example given in the question, C1 would be 900 and C2 would be 60.

**Update**

If the functions are the same but with only different numbers, the general approach is to define the common function and just call it with different parameters:

```
Func<int, int, int, double> f = (T, C1, C2) => Math.Pow( 2, (T - C1) / - C2) - 1;
var Speed = f(T, 900, 60);
```

Another option is to store the functions in array or Dictionary:

```
Func<int, double>[] functions = { T => Math.Pow(2, (T -  900) / -60) - 1,
                                  T => Math.Pow(2, (T - 1200) / -60) - 1,
                                  T => Math.Pow(2, (T -  480) / -35) - 1 };

var Speed = functions[0](T); // calls the first function in the functions array
```

Comment: That's the re-arranged version, but I'd like the code to take the logarithm, and re-arrange it for me, instead of me just typing in the re-arranged version I've put on paper. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: After thinking about this for several hours, I came to the realisation that you aren't far off with this answer. Creating a CAS for this is just outright ludicrous for something this small, and had I known better, I wouldn't have even requested it.

To make this the best answer, I'm going to replace the constants (-900 and -60) with a general formula that can be applied to all logs of the type I'm using. This creates a series of variables which the user can enter values for, which can therefore be computed and solved.